# Why Main() method is called on service start?

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I have an application with one main class It overrides ServiceBase methods and has the Main() static method.
I want to use Main() method when it is called by command line, and OnStart()/OnStop() when it is called from windows service management.

I successfully installed this app as service it with installutils but when I start it the Main() method is called instead of OnStart() as expected.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test
{

    class Program : ServiceBase
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            log.Error("Run as App");
        }


        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            log.Info("Starting service");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            log.Info("Stopping service");
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Windows services have a guilty secret. They start their lives as plain old console applications. It's only after they've started running and register with the service control manager that they're transformed into services.

As such, yes, it's correct that `Main` is the first entrypoint that is called because at that point, it's just a console app.

The way that the service registers with the Service Control Manager and becomes a service is handled by calling `ServiceBase.Run()` from your `Main` method (or a method that it invokes)

Comment: Should I run ServiceBase.Run() when Environment.UserInteractive is false? Seems that ServiceBase.Run() needs a service array as parameter, what should I pass?

Comment: @Tobia - usually, you'd pass it an instance of the class which has the `OnStart` and `OnStop` methods. It takes an array because service processes can actually support/contain multiple services. If you create a new service project in VS it should set this up for you automatically. And pivoting off of `UserInteractive` is quite a common way of distinguishing (but not necessarily 100% foolproof - nothing is)

Comment: I don't know if that's a dirty secret so much as it's an obvious and well-documented manifestation of how pretty much all standalone executable programs work (as opposed to linkable libraries). The compiler sets the program's entry point to the main() method or one of its overloads. Beyond that it is up to the program to register itself with any external context (the service control manager) and also to keep itself running (as opposed to just falling out of the main() method and terminating).

Comment: @Craig - it would be conceivable for an OS to have "native" support for starting different types of binaries in different ways. And, of course, the *managed* entry point is far different from the actual entry point. .NET could have put all of the service machinery behind the scenes and just pretended that OnStart/OnStop etc were the actual entry points into the managed-code portion of a service.

Comment: But they didn't, and name an OS that does it differently.  :). Of course it's conceivably possible. The only magic about the entry point in any binary is that the first instruction in the executable is a goto (jmp) to the address of the entry point function. Sure, in .NET, that jump is to a .NET stub that wraps the rest of the program's lifetime in the .NET runtime environment, then calls your main(), but it's *functionally* the same, and notably Microsoft did NOT pretend that OnStart and OnStop are special cases because that would have to be done in the compiler and would be silly.  :)

Comment: Or the service would have to be a dll and you'd still have to write an exe wrapper to be able to test it or run it independently of actually installing it as a service on a windows machine.

Comment: @Craig - on AmigaOS (classic) on which I got my start, it was fairly standard for compilers to make launch from Workbench and launch from the console act quite differently. In particular, you had to process a window message to get your "startup arguments" rather than having them passed as arguments to a `main()` routine. And VB maintains a fiction that you can have a "startup object" (a Form) rather than writing a `Main`.

Comment: Who's still using VB?  :p. There's a main method buried in that form class. .NET itself isn't working any differently...  the Amiga was great! It's really too bad the Commodore execs plundered the company. Workbench was just loading the exe akin to a dll in that case...

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Test
{

    class Program : ServiceBase
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
                if (System.Environment.UserInteractive)
                {
                    log.Debug("App");
                }
                else
                {
                    ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[] { new Program() });
                }
        }


        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            log.Info("Starting service");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            log.Info("Stopping service");
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Main method also gets called within a service like in any other programm. (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685477(v=vs.85).aspx).

You can use the Property `Environment.UserInteractive` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx) to determine if the app was called by the user or as a service.